# Undesired backspace behavior within terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm using uxrvt-unicode as my terminal. When I type text in the terminal and hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the cursor moves right as if I'm adding whitespace and the deleted characters remain displayed. So if I typed, for instance, `ls` then hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> twice, I'd have `ls`   displayed, however, if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it gets treated as if I'd actually deleted `ls`. Does anyone understand this? Thank you!

Comment: `stty -a` shows the value for *erase*, which may not be what your terminal is sending for "backspace".

Comment: Among other things [this](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_erase) may help.  A typical answer here will confuse "backspace" and "delete".

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I'm going to try this after work today.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I realized that when typing `clear` to clear the terminal display, my terminal responded with `'rxvt-256color': unknown terminal type`. When typing this error message into a Google search, it led me to add `export TERM='xterm-256color'` to the top of my `~/.bashrc` file. This solution ended up solving all my issues!